# How does one create inline Python scripts for use in Splunk search queries?

Tags: python, hex, ascii, splunk

I am creating a simple script to take a hex(base 16) encoded field and convert it to readable text. For this endeavor I have decided to use the built in Python function for strings ".decode("hex")." I would like to use this script in a  search "pipeline" running a field called packet through the statement and creating a new field of decoded text in the process.

I have read the documentation for the API splunk.Intersplunk however I am not 100% understanding what exactly that I need to use to complete my script. Specifically, from the examples I have seen, I do not understand what the following lines do for me?

```
(isgetinfo, sys.argv) = splunk.Intersplunk.isGetInfo(sys.argv)
```

Additionally in the case of collecting results and creating the new field is the following line needed?

```
results = splunk.Intersplunk.readResults(None, None, False)
```

So you are tracking this is what I have thus far and I believe I am close.

```
import sys
import splunk.Intersplunk
import string


#Program takes hex encoded string from a field and outputs value in search results at the gui
(isgetinfo, sys.argv) = splunk.Intersplunk.isGetInfo(sys.argv) #debug to see arguments I think Does it print these out?
results = splunk.Intersplunk.readResults(None, None, False) 

str=""

if len(sys.argv) < 2: # make sure there is an argument passed if not return error
    splunk.Intersplunk.parseError("[!] No arguments provided, please provide one argument.")
    sys.exit(1)

else: #grab the string from sys.argv and make it uppercase because I like uppercase hex strings :)
    str=sys.argv[1]
    str=str.upper()

if all(char in string.hexdigits for char in str): # make sure all characters are hex    
    decoded_string = str.decode("hex")
    splunk.Intersplunk.outputResults(decoded_string)

else: # return an error if its not a hex string
    splunk.Intersplunk.parseError("[!] String provided is not [A-F 0-9], please validate your inputs")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Also I am aware of the need for the STANZA setting below.

```
[decode_hex]
TYPE = python
FILENAME = decode_hex.py
```

Comment: You may want to use the custom search commands modules in the Splunk SDK for Python, you can read the docs here: http://dev.splunk.com/view/python-sdk/SP-CAAAEU2

Comment: Seen it thanks. I suppose I should rephrase question to I dont understand the documentation how do you do this :)

Comment: We have some [examples](https://github.com/splunk/splunk-sdk-python/tree/master/examples/searchcommands_app) and a [template](https://github.com/splunk/splunk-sdk-python/tree/master/examples/searchcommands_template/bin) that may be helpful. If you'd like further guidance, please send us an email at devinfo@splunk.com

Comment: from https://dev.splunk.com/enterprise/docs/devtools/customsearchcommands/v1protocol
If your executable has the attribute supports_getinfo set to true, you should first make a call like:

```(isgetinfo, sys.argv) = splunk.Intersplunk.isGetInfo(sys.argv)```

This call will strip the first argument from sys.argv and check if you are in GETINFO mode or EXECUTE mode. If you are in GETINFO mode, your executable should use splunk.Intersplunk.outputInfo() to return the properties of your executable or splunk.Intersplunk.parseError() if the arguments are invalid.